# I know this claim is false. So what is wrong with the proof? If $A\subseteq B\cup C$, then $A \subseteq B$ or $A\subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\subseteq B\cup C$, then $A \subseteq B$ or $A\subseteq C$. A counterexample to this claim is: $A=\{ 2,3,4 \}$, $B=\{1,2,3\}$, $C=\{3,4,5\}$. But I cannot find an error in this proof: Assume $A\subseteq B\cup C$. Let $x\in A$. Then $x\in B\cup C$. So $x\in B$ or $x\in C$. Case 1. $x\in B$. We have $x\in A \rightarrow x\in B$ Thus $A\subseteq B$. Case 2.  $x\in C$. We have $x\in A \rightarrow x\in C$ Thus $A\subseteq C$. Hence, $A\subseteq B$ or $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: $x$ is just one element.  You have to prove one or the other for *every* element.  You might have $x\in A \subset B; x \not \in C$ but then also have $y \in A \subset C; y \not \in C$.

Comment: In the above proof, how is $x\in A$ not an arbitrary element?

Comment: Because you said "suppose $x \in B$".  You can't say that for an arbitrary element.  Once you suppose $x \in B$ it is no longer an arbitrary element in $A$.  It now has a *specific* property  (that is is also in $B$) that not all elements have.  SO it can not be arbitrary.

Comment: That makes sense. But, since $x\in B \cup C$, is it unsafe to then say that $x$ has to be in either $B$ or $C$? And then prove by cases?

Comment: "arbitrary" a label some elements have.  $2$ is not an arbitrary element, neither is $3$ or $4$.  So ... none of the elements in $A$ are arbitrary?  Well, that's word play.  An "arbitrary element" is one that we don't *KNOW* any specific quality.  One way say, let's suppose $x$ is even, we are assuming specifics and it can't claim it is arbitrary.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to say since $x \in B\cup C$ that either $x \in B$ or $x \in C$.  We just can't say which *one* of those is true.  If we do a case.  "Suppose $x\in B$" we can't continue to say "$x$ can be any element in $A$".  That is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

You have proved that

> for every $x$, if $x\in A$, then either $x\in B$ or $x\in C$

Your claim is

> (for every $x$, if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$) or (for every $x$, if $x\in A$, then $x\in C$)

With logic symbols, the first formula is

> $\forall x\,(x\in A\to ( {x\in B} \lor {x\in C}))$

and the second one is

> $(\forall x\,(x\in A\to x\in B))\lor(\forall x\,(x\in A\to x\in C))$

It should be clear that the two are quite different and, indeed, the simple example $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1\}$, $C=\{2\}$ makes the first true and the second false.

If you examine your proof with this example, you see that for $x=1$ we have $x\in B$, but for $x=2$ we have $x\in C$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a Venn diagram where $B$ and $C$ are your normal two circles, and $A$ is a really thin ellipse passing through the middle of the two.

As far as the proof is concerned, you simply forgot that to prove a subset relation you need to show that **all** elements of one set belong to another. As soon you as you have chosen your $x$ you break into cases, and each time it may be different.

Comment: "As you have chosen your $x$ you break into cases, and each time it may be different." What do you mean by this? It seems as though the $x\in A$ is an arbitrary element of A, and hence the proof should apply to all $x\in A$. I have already drawn that Venn diagram, and I understand the claim is false. I am still puzzled as to where the error is in the proof.

Comment: @PlatonicTradition You did choose an arbitrary element of $A$, but what applies to all $x\in A$ is the disjunction $x\in B$ **or** $x\in C$. When you move into your case by case analysis, you are no longer considering a truly arbitrary member of $A$.

Comment: @PlatonicTradition Also, there was a missing word. I meant to say "As soon as you have chosen"

Comment: @PlatonicTradition Additionally, your cases aren't technically correct either. Your first case can read $x\in B$, but the second case should read $x\not\in B$, thus $x\in C$.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that *one* element $x$ of $A$ belongs to $B$, you can't deduce that $A\subset B$, since this means that *every* element of $A$ belongs to $B$..

Comment: But in the proof, is $x\in A$ not an arbitrary element of A? So that the proof applies for all $x \in A$? Where does the proof go wrong?

Comment: **Each** individual element of $A$ belongs to $B$ or to $C$. It doesn't follow from that that **all** elements of $A$ belong to $B$ or that **all** elements of $A$ belongs to $C$. You provided an example yourself.

Comment: When you picked $x$ it was an arbitrary element.  But *once* you picked it and started playing with it.  It isn't arbitrary.  It is now a specific element.  Suppose you are told you can pick any cat from the pound.  And you pick one at random and you picked Bert.  And you said there's nothing special about picking Bert.  Bert was an arbitrary cat.  That's fine.  Then you look at Bert and see he has tapeworms.  You can't say "well, Bert was arbitrary so I can conclude all the cats had tapeworms."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to prove something if you can see that it is true visually.
So try to draw two venn diagrams B and C and color their union. Now let A be another diagram inside the union of B and C, then what can you see from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get technical $x \in A \to x\in B$ is ambiguous.  It could mean either $\exists x: x\in A \to x \in B$ or it could mean $\forall x: x\in A \to x \in B$.

In your proof, you are saying "Case 1: $x \in B$ therefore $\exists x: x\in A \to x\in B$".  And that is true.  But the definition of "$A \subset B$" requires the statement "$\forall x: x\in A \to x \in B$".  And that is false.

Consider this:  $2\in A$ .  And $2\in B$.  So the sentence "$2\in A \to 2 \in B$" is true (because $M\to N$ means ($M$ and $N$) or (not $M$)).  So "$\exists x: x\in A \to x \in B$" is true.  But that sure as heck does not mean "$\forall x: x \in A \to x \in B$"!

Obviously $x = 4$ would be a counter example.

But to say "$A \subset B$" we must have "$\forall x: x\in A \implies x\in B$".  And you just never had that.

Otherwise....

we could say:

$\mathbb Z \subset (0,3)$.

Pf: Let $x = 1$.  $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in (0,3)$.  So $x \in \mathbb Z \to x\in (0,3)$ so $\mathbb Z \subset (0,3)$.